# An arithmetic Exception

Tags: c++, exception, casting

I'm trying to calculate the Euler's totient function. It works fine with numbers smaller than `10^5`, but it raises an arithmetic exception for large numbers.

```
__int128_t fi(__int128_t n) {
    double result = n;
    for(int i = 0; pr[i] <= n; i++)
        if (n % pr[i] == 0) result *= (1  - (double)1/pr[i]);
    return result;
}
```

I've tried to do explicit casts, but it didn't work out.

`pr` contains prime divisors up to `10^6`.

Comment: Do you really need a 128-bit integer as index into your array? How big will the array `pr` be? You also don't seem to have any check for going out of bounds of the array. And what *is* `pr`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: may be a really strange question, but just to exclude the obvious: does your cpu support 128bit integers?